# W3C Markup Validation gives me 3 errors on one line that seems to work

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I ran my website in the W3C Validator only to be given these errors:

```
<a href="#header-anchor">
        <img src="img/banner.png" width="169" height="54" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

The errors I got are:

- Line 14, column 28: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.
- Line 14, column 28: End tag a violates nesting rules.
- Line 14, column 28: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

I am not sure what is causing this error, so any help will appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Apparently this piece of code is causing the error but I am not sure what it is exactly causing it:

```
<a href="index.html">
```

Edit 2: Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Banner --> 
<a class="anchor" id="header-anchor">
<div id="header-wrapper">
  <header role="banner" id="header"> 
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/banner.png" width="169" height="54" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#header-anchor">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services-anchor">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team-anchor">OUR TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-anchor">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-anchor">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<div id="banner-wrapper">
  <section id="banner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>Tagline</h3>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Services --> 
<a class="anchor" id="services-anchor"></a>
<div class="wrapper">
  <section id="services" class="group">
    <h2>Our Services</h2>
    <div class="floatleft small"> <span class="fa-stack fa-3x"> <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span>
      <h3>Service 1</h3>
      <p>Service 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft small"> <span class="fa-stack fa-3x"> <i class="fa fa-money"></i> </span>
      <h3>Service 1</h3>
      <p>Service 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft small"> <span class="fa-stack fa-3x"> <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> </span>
      <h3>Service 1</h3>
      <p>Service 1</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- About us --> 
<a class="anchor" id="team-anchor"></a>
<section id="team" class="group">
  <h2>Our Team</h2>
  <div class="floatleft mid"> <img src="img/ben.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="Ben Fitchew">
    <h3>Team 1</h3>
    <p>Team 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floatleft mid"> <img src="img/jeremy.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="Jeremy Lang">
    <h3>Team 1</h3>
    <p>Team 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floatright mid"> <img src="img/gianluca.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="Gianluca Monaco">
    <h3>Team 1</h3>
    <p>Team 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floatright mid"> <img src="img/will.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="William Pattisson">
    <h3>Team 1</h3>
    <p>Team 1</p>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- About -->
<div class="wrapper"> <a class="anchor" id="about-anchor"></a>
  <section id="about" class="group" role="main">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>About</p>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Slideshow -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Slideshow</h2>
  <h3>Slideshow</h3>
  <p class="Slideshow"><img src='images/picture1.jpg' name='SlideShow'/></p>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Javascript code --> 
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideShowSpeed = 2000;
var Pic = new Array();

Pic[0]='img/picture1.jpg';
Pic[1]='img/picture2.jpg';
Pic[2]='img/picture3.jpg';
Pic[3]='img/picture4.jpg';
Pic[4]='img/picture5.jpg';
Pic[5]='img/picture6.jpg';

var currentPicture = 1;
var pictureNo = Pic.length;

var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < pictureNo; i++) {
preLoad[i] = new Image();
preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}

function runSlideShow() {

if (document.all) {
document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=2)";
document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDuration=3)";
document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Apply();
}

document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[currentPicture].src;

if (document.all) {
document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Play();
}

currentPicture = currentPicture + 1;

if (currentPicture >= pictureNo)
     currentPicture = 0;

setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed);

}

</script> 
<script>
    runSlideShow();
</script> 
<!-- Contact --> 
<a class="anchor" id="contact-anchor"></a>
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <section id="contact" class="group">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <div id="map-canvas" class="floatleft mid"></div>
    <div class="floatright mid">
      <form id="frmContact" action="mail.php" method="post" role="form">
        <label for="txtName" id="lblName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" aria-labelledby="lblName" required placeholder="Enter your name here" minlength="3" maxlength="70" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+">
        <span class="error_show">Name is not valid!</span>
        <label for="txtEmail" id="lblEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" aria-labelledby="lblEmail" required placeholder="Enter your email here" minlength="5" maxlength="254">
        <span class="error_show">Email is not valid!.</span>
        <label for="txtMessage" id="lblMessage">Message</label>
        <textarea name="txtMessage" id="txtMessage" aria-labelledby="txtMessage" required placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
        <span class="error_show">Message is not valid!</span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message">
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- Javascript --> 
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> 
<script>
            // Code for Google Map
            function initialize() {
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51463,-0.106533);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatLng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Ardevora'
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Form Validation Code
                $('#txtName').on('input', function() {
                    var input=$(this);
                    var is_name=input.val();
                    if (is_name) {
                        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                        input.next().hide();
                    } else {
                        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                        input.next().show();
                    }
                });
                $('#txtEmail').on('input', function() {
                    var input=$(this);
                    var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
                    var is_email=regex.test(input.val());
                    if (is_email) {
                        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                        input.next().hide();
                    } else {
                        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                        input.next().show();
                    }
                });
                $('#txtMessage').keyup(function(event) {
                    var input=$(this);
                    var message=$(this).val();
                    if (message) {
                        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                        input.next().hide();
                    }   else { 
                        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                        input.next().show();
                    }  
                });
                $("#submit").click(function(event) {
                    var form_data=$("#frmContact").serializeArray();
                    var error_free=true;
                    for (var input in form_data){
                        var element=$("#"+form_data[input]['name']);
                        var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
                        var error_element=element.next();
                        if (!valid) {
                            error_element.show();
                            error_free=false;
                        } else { 
                            error_element.hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (!error_free){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });

        </script> 
<!-- Cookie Script --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

  var msg = "We use cookies to enhance your web browsing experience. By continuing to browse the site you agree to our policy on cookie usage.";
  var closeBtnMsg = "Ok I comply";
  var privacyBtnMsg = "Privacy Policy";
  var privacyLink = "http://www.google.com";

  //check cookies 
  if(document.cookie){
   var cookieString = document.cookie;
   var cookieList = cookieString.split(";");
   // if cookie named OKCookie is found, return
   for(x = 0; x < cookieList.length; x++){
     if (cookieList[x].indexOf("OKCookie") != -1){return}; 
   }
  }

  var docRoot = document.body;
  var okC = document.createElement("div");
  okC.setAttribute("id", "okCookie");
  var okCp = document.createElement("p");
  var okcText = document.createTextNode(msg); 

  //close button
  var okCclose = document.createElement("a");
  var okcCloseText = document.createTextNode(closeBtnMsg);
  okCclose.setAttribute("href", "#");
  okCclose.setAttribute("id", "okClose");
  okCclose.appendChild(okcCloseText);
  okCclose.addEventListener("click", closeCookie, false);

  //privacy button
  var okCprivacy = document.createElement("a");
  var okcPrivacyText = document.createTextNode(privacyBtnMsg);
  okCprivacy.setAttribute("href", privacyLink);
  okCprivacy.setAttribute("id", "okCprivacy");
  okCprivacy.appendChild(okcPrivacyText);

  //add to DOM
  okCp.appendChild(okcText);
  okC.appendChild(okCp);
  okC.appendChild(okCclose);
  okC.appendChild(okCprivacy);
  docRoot.appendChild(okC);

  okC.classList.add("okcBeginAnimate");

  function closeCookie(){
    var cookieExpire = new Date();
    cookieExpire.setFullYear(cookieExpire.getFullYear() +2);
    document.cookie="OKCookie=1; expires=" + cookieExpire.toGMTString() + ";";
    docRoot.removeChild(okC);
  }

})();
</script> 
<!-- Footer -->
<footer role="contentinfo"> 
  <!-- Left Footer -->
  <ul class="floatleft">
    <li><a href="#header-anchor">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services-anchor">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team-anchor">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-anchor">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-anchor">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Right Footer -->
  <ul class="floatright">
    <p>Copyright 2014</p>
  </ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not closing the `<a href="index.html">` tag

Comment: It is closed    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/banner.png" width="169" height="54" alt="Logo">
    </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your declaration of page? Likely to be a bug in the non-completion of the `<img />` tag.

```
<img src="img/banner.png" width="169" height="54" alt="Logo" />
```

Tag `<a>` should have a `title="Title a"` consistent with `alt="Alt img"` image

Comment: I tried, that and I still get the same, sorry I should have been more precise on what part of the code is causing it, thank you for helping.

Comment: I set this to: <!DOCTYPE HTML>, should I change it?

Comment: Sure check the the main question again

Comment: `<a class="anchor" id="header-anchor">` is not closed !!

Comment: Alrighty that closing tag gives out more errors. You think i should fix those or leave it be?

Comment: 1. What means `name='SlideShow'` in `<img>`?,  2. Line 87. `</section>` is not opened. 3. Correct attributes in input [Attributes in input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: Alright, after fixing the various problems, the website has passed the validation. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: This answer does not address the problem. Some comments point to the right direction, but that does not justify accepting the answer.

Comment: I tried to help (successfully), you just criticize.

Comment: Accepting an answer that does not answer the problem asked is not helpful to future visitors. And helping them is the purpose of accepting answers (and voting answers up or down).

Comment: Problem is in the question, not in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<a class="anchor" id="header-anchor">` has no closing tag. This causes the elements after it to be taken as its content, which in turn leads to violation of element nesting rules. The simplest fix is to add the closing tag immediately after the start tag:

```
<a class="anchor" id="header-anchor"></a>
```

Such an element is not good style, though. You can probably work with just `id` attributes and `class` attributes assigned to elements with real content.

Fixing the problem causes some errors later in the document to be reported, but they are relatively easy to analyze (especially with the help of the explanations).